# unchosen program is not sent to the background

Tags: gui, taskbar

I have a terminal and chrome open.

both appear in the taskbar.

I click one of them and the gui appears,
then I click on the second from them but the gui appears behind the existing gui.

meaning I cannot see the termianl if the chrome is opened. I have to minimize the chrome and then the terminal is visible on the screen.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use side-apps using the easy way, or the hard way:

Easy way:
Drag any app to the left side or right side (2 apps) or any quarter and Ubuntu will do it for you. You can also make an app fullscreen by dragging it to the top (center).

Hard way:
Resize the applications to your liking.